# Is it possible to use two models depending on database structure?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using winforms and EF with database first aproach. The application connects to a database that is created by another external application, and it's known it can have two different variants.

```
Different table name:   car                 | CAR
                        --------            | ---------
                        Id                  | Id
Different field:        car_description     | CAR_DESCRIPT
Different field:        car_name            | car_NAME
```

So, the code used for the two of them will be for example:

```
context.car.car_description
```

or

```
context.CAR.CAR_DESCRIPT
```

I don't want to compile two times the project making the changes to the model and the code, because the logic is still the same but the field names change. I don't want to mantain two versions either.

Is it possible to use two different models dynamically depending on the database to connect?

Comment: Have you looked at https://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I would typically define a base Car class for all your logic and reasoning about cars.

Then I would construct db1Car and db2Car classes that extend that Car class, and implement its members.

Or turn the order around for a more top-down approach: create both models, and on the lowest level, make it inherit from BaseCar, and move logic and reasoning at business logic level there.

Answer (score 1):

If model first is your only option, you could define two EDMX models that generate identical entity objects -- the name of your database fields do not have to match the name of your classes, you can tell EF to map them differently. From there, you can use different connection strings to produce different conceptual models, but the class definitions would be the same. I've never tried it, but in theory it should work.

If changing to Code First is an option, you can achieve this goal by using the Fluent API and separate mapping classes to configure your code first entities. In your `DbContext`, you override your `OnModelCreating`, you can do:

```
if ( usingSchema1 )
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity1Schema1Map());
}
else
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity1Schema2Map());
}
```